# Default tag and custom subtag to commits

Tags: git, scrum, git-tag

In the realm of **Scrum**, suppose I have the task at hand being the **Sprint 15**.

Naturally I'll create the `sprint15` branch.

The **Sprint 15** consists of multiple **PBIs** from the **Product Backlog**, in this case `pbi131`, `pbi132`, `pbi133` and `pbi134`.

After all **PBIs** from **Sprint 15** are successfully completed and the branch is merged with master, I would like to have all those commits from `sprint15` branch tagged as `sprint15`, but also particular commits tagged as one of the **PBIs** previously mentioned.

Then, is it possible to have a default tag + custom tag when commiting and pushing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common practice is to just mention the numbers of issues or backlog items, or whatever the current buzzword is, in the commit messages.

Any self-respecting issue tracker is then able to associate the commit with the issue.

And yes, tags are unique, you can't apply them to multiple objects.

Answer (score 0):

After some more researching I discovered that a tag can be applied to a single commit only. So it is not possible to do what I wanted.